# Python - Put new line into file at largest indent

Tags: python

Okay so my question involves using PYTHON language please - Nothing else.

Basically, I have a file with a layout such as below:

```
       X
   Y
Z
      A
  B
C
               1
          2
   3
```

And I would look at that and say `X, A and 1 mark a new step!` (because their indent is larger than the previous line basically). So I want to put in a new line with text `Step 1`, `Step 2` etc, for each new step.

Note: I care more about how to put the new line in at the correct place, than how to increase the value of N with each Step.

Note 2: The file will vary in row count, so I cannot simply use at line 3, 6, 9 etc.. That's useless to me unfortunately.

Comment: Post the code of what you tried to solve this problem.

Comment: Ah, should've pointed out that I'm fairly new to python so I've tried inserting text '\nStep 1\n' at line X which works (the \n gives me a 'line buffer' above and below each Step so I can better read my data). But beyond that I've been unable to find anything to do the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want a code something like -

```
start = 1
lines = ['Step' + str(start) + ':\n']
with open('file.txt','r') as inF:
    prevspace = -1
    for line in inF:
        lspaces = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        if lspaces > prevspace and prevspace != -1:
            lines.append('Step' + str(start+1) + ':\n')
            start = start + 1
            lines.append(line)
            prevspace = lspaces
        else:
            lines.append(line)
            prevspace = lspaces
    ifF.close()

with open('newfile.txt','w') as outF:
    for line in lines:
        outF.write(line)
    outF.flush()
    outF.close()
```

Comment: Awesome. Just tried exactly the above and it just about works perfectly! I'm going to try and modify it so it only affects lines between line 4 and line 3 from the bottom.

Thanks for your help!! I'd give you an upvote but apparently I'm not allowed :(

Comment: Done it now ;) Cheers (is it obvious I'm new to this website? haha).

Comment: its not obvious, I just tell everyone how to do it, just in case :) , anyway its not bad to be new, everyone was once new to everything